# manipulating JSON object in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I am using angular and I am using $http.get to get a JSON response back and I set it equal to `$scope.myObjects` .

When I use `ng-repeat="object in myObjects"` in the html, it works.

I wanted to know, is there a way to manipulate these objects? I want to create a property called `myBoolean` and for each object in `myObject` set `myBoolean` to `true`.

When trying to manipulate this object in the controller by doing something like:
`$scope.myObjects.something` I get `myObjects is undefined`

when I try to view the JSON response in the browser all I see is [object Object]. Is there a tool to view the JSON response?

EDIT:
here is my html

```
<div class="comment" ng-hide="loading" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    <h3>Comment <% comment.id %> <small>by <% comment.author %></h3>
    <p><% comment.text %></p>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><a href="#" ng-click="deleteComment(comment.id)" class="text-muted">Delete</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my controller

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])


.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, Comment) {

$scope.commentData = {};


$scope.loading = true;


Comment.get()
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.comments = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
});
```

and my service

```
angular.module('commentService', [])

.factory('Comment', function($http) {

return {
    // get all the comments
    get : function() {
        return $http.get('/api/comments');
    },
});
```

Comment: Check if data coming from get call is not undefined

Comment: When I do ```document.write("<p>" +$http.get('/api/comments') + "</p>");``` I get  [object Object]. Also as I wrote in the html when I iterate through the object, i can see it works. Is there a better way than document write? sorry, i'm new at this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `$scope.myObjects` is an array (i.e `[]`) , not an object (i.e `{}`).

So, you would have to loop through the array and access the elements inside them one by one.

```
angular.forEach($scope.myObjects, function(myObject){
    myObject.myBoolean = true;
});

console.log($scope.myObjects);
```

Comment: Where do I do this? For example http://plnkr.co/edit/Wuc6M7?p=preview here. If I put your code directly after the $http.get call in the controller, it doesn't work

Comment: Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/JaOmApdtauNyRWqQO65U?p=preview

Uses $scope.todos instead of $scope.myObjects

Comment: I tried with todos as well. I tried it after the get method was done though. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$scope.myObjects is actually an array. So to manipulate items present in this scoped variable, you need to iterate it using a loop. For example:

```
for (index  = 0; index < $scope.myObjects.length; index++) {
  $scope.myObjects[index].myBoolean = yourValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` can repeat a list of items like an array of items/objects of items, but not an Object.

If we do like this:

```
$scope.myObjects.something = myBoolean;
```

it will override the collection so `ng-repeat` will fail.

Use it like this

```js
Comment.get()
 .success(function(data) {
     $scope.comments = data;
     angular.forEach($scope.comments, function(comment) {
         comment.canEdit = true; // hear we will get each comment so we can set property and value to each commnent
     });
     $scope.loading = false;
 });
```